# error al llamar lista de usuarios con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

saben xq al hacer la llamada en el Search (Sin datos) y haber seleccionado FREELANCER, me devuelve una lista de usuario completa osea todos los usuarios de todos los roles y tipo. cuandlo solo quiero listar los Freelancer?

**Codigo del form search**:

```
 <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET" class="flex-grow-1">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <a class="text-reset bg-soft-secondary fs-12 rounded-left d-lg-none p-2" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="class-toggle" data-target=".front-header-search">
                                <i class="las la-arrow-left la-2x"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend flex-grow-1 d-none d-sm-block">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="I'm looking for" name="keyword">
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control aiz-selectpicker" name="type">
                                <option value="freelancer" @isset($type)
                                    @if ($type = 'freelancer')
                                        selected
                                    @endif
                                @endisset>{{ translate('Freelancers') }}</option>
                                <option value="project" @isset($type)
                                    @if ($type == 'project')
                                        selected
                                    @endif
                                @endisset>{{ translate('Projects') }}</option>
                                <option value="service" @isset($type)
                                    @if ($type == 'service')
                                        selected
                                    @endif
                                @endisset>{{ translate('Services') }}</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">
                                    <i class="las la-search la-rotate-270"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**y este es el controlador del Search:**

```
public function index(Request $request){
    if($request->type == 'freelancer'){
        $type = 'freelancer';
        $keyword = $request->keyword;
        $rating = $request->rating;

        $freelancers = UserProfile::query();

        if($request->keyword != null){
            $user_ids = User::where('user_type', 'freelancer')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->pluck('id');
            $freelancers = $freelancers->whereIn('user_id', $user_ids);
        }

        if($request->rating != null){
            if ($rating == "4+") {
                $freelancers = $freelancers->where('rating', '>', 4);
            }
            else {
                $freelancers = $freelancers->whereIn('rating', explode('-', $rating));
            }
        }

        $total = count($freelancers->get());
        $freelancers = $freelancers->paginate(8)->appends($request->query());
        return view('frontend.default.freelancers-listing', compact('freelancers', 'total', 'keyword', 'type', 'rating'));
    } else if($request->type == 'service'){
        $type = 'service';
        $keyword = $request->keyword;
        $rating = $request->rating;

        $services = Service::where('id', '!=', null);

        if($request->keyword != null){
            $service_ids = Service::where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->pluck('id');
            $services = $services->whereIn('id', $service_ids);
        }


        $total = count($services->get());
        $services = $services->paginate(8)->appends($request->query());
        return view('frontend.default.services-listing', compact('services', 'total', 'keyword', 'type', 'rating'));
    }
    else {
        $type = 'project';
        $keyword = $request->keyword;
        $projectType = array('Fixed', 'Long Term');
        $bids = $request->bids;
        $sort = $request->sort;
        $category_id = (ProjectCategory::where('slug', $request->category)->first() != null) ? ProjectCategory::where('slug', $request->category)->first()->id : null;
        $category_ids = CategoryUtility::children_ids($category_id);
        $category_ids[] = $category_id;

        $project_approval = SystemConfiguration::where('type','project_approval')->first()->value;
        if($project_approval == 1){
            $projects = Project::biddable()->notcancel()->open()->where('private', '0')->where('project_approval',1);
        }else{
            $projects = Project::biddable()->notcancel()->open()->where('private', '0');
        }

        if($category_id != null){
            $projects = $projects->whereIn('project_category_id', $category_ids);
        }

        $projects = $projects->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');

        if($request->projectType != null){
            $projectType = $request->projectType;
            $projects = $projects->whereIn('type', $projectType);
        }

        if($request->bids != null){
            if ($bids == "30+") {
                $projects = $projects->where('bids', '>', 30);
            }
            else {
                $projects = $projects->whereIn('bids', explode('-', $bids));
            }
        }

        switch ($sort) {
            case '1':
                $projects = $projects->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                break;
            case '2':
                $projects = $projects->orderBy('price', 'asc');
                break;
            case '3':
                $projects = $projects->orderBy('price', 'desc');
                break;
            case '4':
                $projects = $projects->orderBy('bids', 'asc');
                break;
            case '5':
                $projects = $projects->orderBy('bids', 'desc');
                break;
            default:
                $projects = $projects->latest();
                break;
        }

        $total = count($projects->get());
        $projects = $projects->paginate(8)->appends($request->query());
        return view('frontend.default.projects-listing', compact('projects', 'keyword', 'total', 'type', 'projectType', 'bids', 'sort', 'category_id'));
    }
}

public function searchBySkill(Request $request, $id, $type){
    $skill = Skill::findOrFail($id);

    $keyword = $request->keyword;
    $projectType = array('Fixed', 'Long Term');
    $bids = $request->bids;
    $sort = $request->sort;

    if($type == 'projects'){
        $project_approval = SystemConfiguration::where('type','project_approval')->first()->value;
        if($project_approval == 1){
            $projects = Project::biddable()->notcancel()->open()->where('private', '0')->where('project_approval',1);
        }else{
            $projects = Project::biddable()->notcancel()->open()->where('private', '0');
        }

        $projects = $projects->where('skills', 'like', '%'.'"'.$id.'"'.'%')->latest();
        $total = count($projects->get());
        $projects = $projects->paginate(8)->appends($request->query());
        return view('frontend.default.projects-listing', compact('projects', 'keyword', 'total', 'type', 'projectType', 'bids', 'sort'));
    }
}
```

donde esta el error ?

mi tabla es:
user y dentro de ella esta:
id
provider_id
user_type
name

Dentro de ''user_type''  tengo los 2 tipo de usuarios : freelance y client.

pero aun así me lista todos los usuarios y solo quiero que llame a los freelance, en la vista tengo:

```
                        @foreach ($freelancers as $key => $freelancer)
                            
                            <h5 class="fw-600 mb-1">{{ $freelancer->user->user_type }}</h5>
                        @endforeach
```

que puedo hacer para solo listar los usuarios freelance??

Comment: Viendo un poco el codigo por encima parece que la condicion `where('user_type', 'freelancer')` solo se esta aplicando cuando `$request->keyword != null` en lugar de siempre que es `$request->type == 'freelancer'`, si no entiendo mal lo que quieres hacer este where deberia esta fuera del condicional `if($request->keyword != null)`

Comment: vale, ya pruebo te consejo

Answer (score 0):

La solución que halle fue cambiar :

```
if($request->keyword != null){
```

por esto:

```
if($request->keyword = 'freelance'){
```

ahora funciona bien el codigo

Comment: Lo intente con == y con ===   y no funcionaba, al añadir 'freelance'  vi que funciono, realice unas pruebas y el formulario hace el trabajo que deseo.

Comment: vale te entiendo,

Comment: Lo probé de esta manera :  if($request->keyword == 'freelance'){    y si me lista los freelance pero al realizar una busqueda por nombre4 del freelance tambien me llamaba a los usuarios con otro, roll.

Comment: lo are, gracias por tu consejo